# How can i fix MongoDB error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How can fix this mongodb error?: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. I tried fixing it by saying if one of the conditions is undefined to return, but that won't solve it.

I seem to get the error if none of the below conditions is met:

```js
const options = { upsert: false };
if (user.endurance < 5 && user.energy > 40) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -40,
    },
};
}
if (user.endurance >= 5 && user.energy > 38) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -38,
    },
};
}
if (user.endurance >= 10 && user.energy > 36) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -36,
    },
};
}
if (user.endurance >= 20 && user.energy > 34) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -34,
    },
};
}
if (user.endurance >= 30 && user.energy > 32) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -32,
    },
};
}
if (user.endurance >= 40 && user.energy > 30) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -30,
    },
};
}
if (user.endurance >= 50 && user.energy > 28) {
var updateDoc = {
    $inc: {
        energy: -28,
    }
}
} else if (user.endurance == undefined || user.energy == undefined) return
```

How could i fix this problem?

Comment: Use ```console.log(user)``` and see whether it is what you expected

Comment: Yes it is still as i expected, it shows the user schema values. And because it did not meet the requirements it shouldn't remove any energy which it didn't.  But that still wont explain why i get this error.

Comment: Because your `else if` , which discards undefined values and therefore prevents `undefined` errors, applies only if the last condition is not met. Remove the `else`. And also, put the last line at the top. If one of the values is undefined, return immediately, don't waste time checking every `if() if() if()`, they'll all be false.

Comment: Hmm i tried that but that doesn't seem to remove the error. The weird thing is that the code works as intended but still shows me the error.

Comment: I forgot to mention i also get this:
node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:796:23)
node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\update_one.js:11:10)
node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:758:5)